# Sending an Excel file from Bot to User in Microsoft Bot framework V4

Tags: .net-core, botframework

I am developing a Bot application using MS bot framework V4. I want to send Excel file (.xlsx) from Bot to the user, it is a template which user later fills in and send back to Bot. But with the following code, I can see the file in the chat window but user is not able to download the file. How can I achieve this functionality where user can download it.
Note: Please see the *ELSE* part below where user is supposed to download the Excel template.

```
 private async Task<DialogTurnResult> UploadFileTemplateCheckStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string choice = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;
        if (choice.ToLower().Equals("yes"))
        {
            stepContext.Values["IsFileTemplate"] = (string)stepContext.Result;
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions
            { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please upload the file.") }, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            //Provide the template.
            var ImagePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "TeeUpTemplate.xlsx");
            var ImageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath));
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
            {
                Name = "TeeUpTemplate.xlsx", ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                ThumbnailUrl = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Excel.png"),
                ContentUrl = $"data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,{ImageData}"
            };

            IMessageActivity reply = MessageFactory.Text("Use this template to fill the file.");
            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            reply.From = stepContext.Context.Activity.From;
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions
            { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Upload the file") }, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What bot channel(s) are you testing and do you need this to work with?

Comment: I am using Bot Emulator for dev purposes. Later will use MS teams platform.

Comment: Anyone who can answer to this?

Comment: @GaurangNaik - how do you manage for this, i am looking for same.

Comment: Not yet managed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I implemented. If your bot works with attachments then one of the method is One Drive subscription or sharepoint subscription. It is a mandate. I used One Drive subscription. All the attachment first gets uploaded or downloaded to your One Drive Account from where it goes to the bot.

The major drawback for developers is you can not test this in Bot Emulator, it has to be
tested directly in Teams as `Content Type = application/vnd.microsoft.teams.file.download.info` only has support in Teams.

One more point is you will have to upload Manifest file with file with

```
"supportsFiles": true,
```

You may refer this sample for C# to get more insights:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload

Thank you.